# Flutter - Flutter_webview_pro - Couldn't find meta data for provider with authority com.example

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying flutter platform and following examples in the documentation.

I succeeded in running flutter getting started example and then added flutter_webview_pro module which also is working.

The problem is that when I try to use a `<input type="file">` field, I receive the error "Couldn't find meta data for provider with authority com.example...." This message is after I receive the request permision to use camera notice and agree to it.

In pubsec.yaml I added the following :

```
flutter_webview_pro: ^3.0.1+3
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  camera: ^0.10.0+1
```

In main.dart i have :

```
import 'package:flutter_webview_pro/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong? I looked all over the documentation of flutter_webview_pro and couldn't find anything that describes this situation and how to solve it.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I just found the answer from offical doc in github. See: https://github.com/wenzhiming/flutter_webview_pro/blob/master/FAQ.md

Answer (score 0):

insert codes into AndroidMenifast.xml

```
<application> 
    ...    
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.rtzl.zijinscanner.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    ...
</application>
```

then create provider_paths.xml add codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    </paths>
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).